# Why MetaSpace Size is twice as big as Used MetaSpace?

Tags: java, memory, jvm, out-of-memory, metaspace

I wrote a program to simulate MetaSpace OOM. But I found that `MetaSpace Size` is almost always twice as big as `Used MetaSpace`. Why?

I run my program with flag `-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=50m`, the program throw OOM when `Used MetaSpace` reached about 25M rather than 50M, Why?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I measure fragmentation in Hotspot's Metaspace?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32117471/how-do-i-measure-fragmentation-in-hotspots-metaspace)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following two experiment will explain what does the gap between *MetaSpace Size* and *Used MetaSpace* mean:

**EXP-1**: load one class per ClassLoader, I got this:
[image]

**EXP-2**: load five classes per ClassLoader, I got this:
[image]

As **[Java 8 document](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/considerations.html)** says:

> Space is requested from the OS and then divided into chunks. A class loader allocates space for metadata from its chunks (a chunk is bound to a specific class loader).

I think it means a chunk can contains usually more than one class, so utilization rate of MetaSpace Size grows as you load more classes per ClassLoader.

You can reappear the results by running **[code here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx69N5pLghi8a1pabVlVa0QtRDg/view?usp=sharing)** using command:

```
java -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=50m MetadataOOMSimulator 100000000
```

**Attention**: make sure that all classes be loaded should not appear in `CLASSPATH` (usually include current directory), or those classes will be loaded by APPClassLoader rather than customized ClassLoader.

Answer (score 0):

Good question ;-)

Have a look at this pretty good article.

[PermGenSpace vs MetaSpace](https://dzone.com/articles/java-8-permgen-metaspace)

Comment: If you believe the link answers the question, you should summarise your finding in your answer instead of posting a link-only answer.

Comment: Yes you are right but I was writing this on my smartphone while waiting for a flight... Typing on this is horrible.

Comment: And you are also right that it doesn't really answer the question. Stupid me...  I red this article a year ago and was sure it explains this behavior. But it only notes it.